# Execute Ant for web-applications in Intellij Idea

Tags: ant, intellij-idea

When I trying to run Ant — he show me an alert with “Project JDK not specified”. How I can use Ant in Intellij Idea for web-applications without JDK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You still need JDK configured for Ant to work, either in the Project or in the [Build file properties dialog](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/build-file-properties.html) (you can set custom JDK just for Ant).

Comment: Please check out my solution below

Answer (score 12):

Open the Project Structure dialog (press Command + Semicolon shortcut).  Navigate to the SDKs in the left pane.  In the middle pane, click the + (add), and select "JDK".  Make sure you have the JDK installed (available from the Oracle website), and navigate to the root of that location.  Click OK.  Then open the Ant Build pane on the right side.  Right click the build and select Properties.  Go to the Execution tab and from the "Run under JDK" drop-down, select the JDK version that you set up prior.